# Best approach to making sequential POST requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

So I have an array that contains data that needs to be sent as part of the payload for POST requests that need to be made. Now, these need to be made sequentially, since I need to display the particular payload , then the result(the result being the response that is returned after making the POST request with the payload), then the next payload, then the next result and so on, on my page. I was just wondering what would be the best approach to accomplish this.So this is how I'm approaching it at the moment:

```
for (var i = 0; i < quotesList.length; i++) {
var response = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify(quotesList[i]),
      success: add_to_page,
      },
      timeout: 300000,
      error: function(){
            console.log("Some Error!")
        },
      contentType: "application/json"
})
```

Obviously, the issue here that arises is there's no guarantee in terms of the getting that sequence right and also I wasn't quite sure how exactly to keep a track of the payload since trying to add it as a part of the success function only gets me the last element in the last(presumably the last request thats fired)

Comment: Well you can send only 1 post request and get all the data of all the request but don't show the entire data but you can show only desired data as the user do some action, this way you will have control over your data and user actions as well.

Comment: You can use recursion for archive this.

Comment: Try ```async: false``` along with other ```ajax``` options.

Comment: @KalpashreeV.Bal I don't need it to be synchronous, I just need it to be sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
let quotesListIndex = 0;
function sendAjaxCall() {
  if (quotesListIndex < quotesList.length) {
    var response = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify(quotesList[quotesListIndex++]),
      success: function () {
        //... Add code here

        sendAjaxCall();     // Call the function again for next request      

      },
      timeout: 300000,
      error: function () {
        console.log("Some Error!")
      },
      contentType: "application/json"
    })
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Add one global variable to track the index. and call function recursively. Once the index reached the array size then return from function.

Comment: `quotesList.length` - length is a property, not a method